# Firefox addon open tab and modify in onready event

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to open webpage and automatically fill in login information. My main.js addon code is given below. I have uname and upass variable. I want to fill in the login form using those when addon opens the tab.

```
  var uname="username";
  var upass="password";

  tabs.open({
  url: "https://www.facebook.com",
  onReady:runScript
  });

  function runScript(tab) {
    tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("mody.js")
  });
```

I put this code in my mody.js file:

```
  document.getElementById("email").value=uname;  // uname undefined
  document.getElementById("pass").value=upass; // upass undefined
```

But I can't access these variables from mody.js. Is there any way to pass this variable to the login page?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [contentScriptOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Passing_configuration_options) for this.

> The contentScriptOptions is a JSON object that is exposed to content
>   scripts as a read-only value under the self.options property: